# Get user-id of user in direct message slack channel

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

We're developing a Slack bot and one of the slash commands should - when used in a direct message channel - be able to determine the Slack user-id of the target user in the direct message channel. So for example, imagine 3 Slack users User1, User2 and User3. If User1 would do a `/someaction` in his direct message channel with User3, the Slack server will post the following attributes to our implementation of the `/someaction` command:

```
token
team_id
team_domain
channel_id
channel_name=directmessage
user_id
user_name=User1
command=%2Fsomeaction
text=
response_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhooks.slack.com%2Fcommands%2/........
trigger_id=....
```

`user_id/user_name` are the ones from the person issued the command, so User1 in this case.

To get the `user_id` of User3 we use the [`conversations.info`](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info) API, where we pass in the `channel_id` that is provided to the `/someaction` command above.

Now the problem is that when User1 issue the command in Slack it does work, but when User2 does it (in his direct message channel with User3), it does not work. We did notice that the channel_id provided differs between the invocation of User1 and User2, which makes sense because both have their own direct message channel with User3

Response from User2

```
curl https://slack.com/api/conversations.info?token=TOKEN\&channel=D0123456G&pretty=1
{
    "ok": false,
    "error": "channel_not_found"
}
```

Questions:

1. Why does it work for User1, but not for User2? The only thing we can imagine is that User1 has deployed the Slack app in the Slack workspace. But that should not influence this behavior or should it?
2. Is there another way to get the user id of the target user of a direct message channel based on the channel_id of that direct message channel?

Comment: Oh... well-formulated question!

Comment: You could let everyone in the Slack workspace authorize your app with the scope of reading direct messages & private channels would let this happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this approach does not work in the direct message channel between User 2 and User 3 is that your app has no access to that channel and therefore you get `channel not found` when calling `conversations.info` on that channel.

And it has no access because it has been installed by User 1 and therefore the app can only see channels that User 1 has access to. This is due to how the security architecture in Slack works.

To my knowledge it is not possible to get the user ID of the other member of a direct message channel from a slash command.

Comment: "This is due to how the security architecture in Slack works." I understand the explanation - thanks - but this seems weird to me. Why would it matter for an app's functionality who installed it? When I install a Slack app in a team, I would like all team members to use it identically (in channels, private channels, direct messages and private chats)... and not different for me than for the other dozen or hundreds of users. Selecting the private channels to only the ones the installer has access to, is strange. I'd argue that Slack could change this behavior for the better...

Comment: @JochemSchulenklopper I can understand your point of view. However, that is how Slack is designed. For them channel security has priority. This is why even the superuser of a Slack team ("primary owner") has no access to private channels he is not invited too.

Comment: @ErikKalkhoven, I see; thanks. They could still support this, perhaps taking into account the app scope and necessary rights. Gero mentions that the app is using slash commands, so the only (?) information the app can receive is being entered by the persons having access to that (private) channel or private chat. And the strange thing is that the app / slash command works fine in Slack client, also in a private chat/channel. The strange thing is that the Slack API does not return the information to the app  - info that's being available by any participant in that (private) channel or chat.